# VIM and custom tagging

Tags: vim, tags

I am using vim in windows to edit assembly code.  It is a nonstandard language and disassembly of the binary is done by a custom script so I define the format myself.  I would like to use tags to be able to jump through the code for subroutine calls.  I have searched around quite a bit and all roads seem to lead to using ctags to generate a tags file, but obviously this won't work in my case as I am not dealing with C code.  How is it possible to create a custom tag file?   Here is an example of the code.  First, each subroutine is defined by the keyword and the hex offset (the first column).

```
Subroutine e2b7

e2b7 2c c0 11 03 BBS [Branch if bits are '1'] #$03, $11c0, 00e2ce ($12)
e2bc a9 00       LDA [Load A with mem] #$00
. blah
. blah 
. blah
```

And somewhere in the code a jump to the sub is executed;

```
d9ad 20 b7 e2    JSR $e2b7
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 5):

Use ctags together with the taglist-plugin (http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=273).
The source package of ctags contains the file EXTENDING.html which 
describes how to define an extension. I did this for several languages.
Here two examples (make(1) and POD (perl old document)):

```
%%%%%%%%%%  file '~/.ctags' %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

--langmap=perl:+.pod
--regex-perl=/^=head1[[:space:]]*(.+)/\1/o,pod/
--regex-perl=/^=head2[[:space:]]*(.+)$/. \1/o,pod/
--regex-perl=/^=head3[[:space:]]*(.+)$/.. \1/o,pod/
--regex-perl=/^=head4[[:space:]]*(.+)$/... \1/o,pod/
--regex-perl=/^=for[[:space:]]+([^:]+):(.*)$/*\1:\2/o,pod/
--regex-perl=/^__(DATA|END)__$/__\1__/l,labels/

--regex-make=/^([^:# \t]+)[ \t]*:($|[^=]+)/\1/t,targets/
```

To use this with taglist you need two additional lines in ~/.vimrc .
For the above examples:

```
%%%%%%%%%%  file '~/.vimrc' %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

let tlist_perl_settings  = 'perl;c:constants;f:formats;l:labels;p:packages;s:subroutines;d:subroutines;o:POD'
let tlist_make_settings  = 'make;m:makros;t:targets'
```

This [screenshot](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-perl/taglist.png) shows the taglist navigation window 
with additional POD section.

Answer (score 2):

[ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html) supports a **lot** of languages, including assembly -- if your favorite variant isn't included, perhaps you could add it in...?